# Laravel 5.4 Error in Model Post Class Not Found in Web.php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with my Model Class being `app/Post`. 
My routes are in `Web.php`.

This file contains the following code:

```
use app\Post;

Route::get('/find', function(){
  $result = Post::all(); 
});
```

But this gave me an error.

Comment: What is the error code that you received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using model inside the closure, you must use full namespace:

```
Route::get('/find', function() {
    $result = App\Post::all();
});
```

Or use correct namespace:

```
use App\Post;
```

However, it's a bad practice to use closures. Put your logic into controllers, models etc instead.

Comment: This is not necessary if since he defined the `use` statement.

Comment: Thankyou guyz. Btw Problem Solved. my Mistake was use app/Post;